# f:validateRegex causes exception

Tags: java, jsf

I want to validate that an input is strictly numerical consisting of between 10-16 characters long.  Based on the user input value I was going to have a message appear below the input field. The problem is, when I go to use `<f:validateRegex>` to help accomplish this, it causes the app to throw an exception.

I am new to JSF and I am having a difficult time thinking of ways to debug the application.  The scope of my work is supposed to only really include UI enhancements for now... So I'd like to avoid using a validator class if possible.

here's the troublesome code.  Note:  if i remove the  tag or comment it out, the page that I'm working will reload without issue.  Currently, due to the app throwing an exception, the page app will not deliver any code to a requesting browser.

```
<h:inputText id="idNum" value="#{object.var}" 
    styleClass="form-control idNum" maxlength="16" 
    required="true" autocomplete="off">
   <f:validateRegex 
      pattern="\^([0-9][\S][^\sa-zA-Z,./;:!:@#$%&*()<>_+~`{}]{8,14})*$\g" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="idNum" />
```

I'd be happy to provide any additional detail.  However, i'm not sure what additional details are relevant at this point.  For starters, here's the stack trace:

```
[8/29/19 21:37:52:386 CDT] 00000093 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause Faces Servlet: javax.servlet.ServletException: null source
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1237)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.openfaces.util.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:120)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at org.work.app.auth.filter.HeaderFilter.doFilter(HeaderFilter.java:27)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:948)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
    at java.util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:67)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.<init>(SystemEvent.java:67)
    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.<init>(ComponentSystemEvent.java:69)
    at javax.faces.event.PostRestoreStateEvent.<init>(PostRestoreStateEvent.java:69)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:256)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:245)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    ... 32 more

[8/29/19 21:37:52:387 CDT] 00000093 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Faces Servlet]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
    at java.util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:67)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.<init>(SystemEvent.java:67)
    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.<init>(ComponentSystemEvent.java:69)
    at javax.faces.event.PostRestoreStateEvent.<init>(PostRestoreStateEvent.java:69)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:256)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:245)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1237)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.openfaces.util.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:120)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at org.work.app.auth.filter.HeaderFilter.doFilter(HeaderFilter.java:27)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:948)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

Comment: 1: [mcve] please (including a more simple regex) 2: jsf implementation and version info please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF, validateRegex and & (ampersand)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462136/jsf-validateregex-and-ampersand)

Comment: After solving this, next problem eclipse warns me about is: `The value of attribute "pattern" associated with an element type "f:validateRegex" must not contain the '<' 
 character.` - replace this by `&lt;`

Comment: the combination of the ampersand `&` and `<` fixes, the page was loading just fine.  Now it is back to not loading.  I am trying to troubleshoot the regex to see if the page will end up loading.  Here's where I'm at so far:  `<f:validateRegex pattern="\^([0-9][\S][^&amp;][^\s][^a-z][^A-Z][^,./;:!:@#$%*()_+`{}]{8,14})*$\g" />`.  In the meantime, the web app is running on Websphere Application Server V8.5 which according to [this URL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rovr_specs.html) it's JSF 2.0.

Comment: Don't chameleonize your question. Now all comments that were here seem out of order. If you solved the original problem, revert the edit, create an answer and for the new question, create a new question!

Comment: sorry.  i'm fixing it now

Comment: @Kukeltje can you remove your downvote?  i fixed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the regex which was causing the error.  Per the comments, there were at least two culprits causing a problem the `&` and the `<`.  However, just fixing those did not fix the issue.  Here's what i did to fix the input.

```
<h:inputText id="idNum" value="#{object.var}" styleClass="form-control idNum" 
    maxlength="16" required="true" autocomplete="off" requiredMessage="" validatorMessage="No dashes or spaces" binding="#{idNum}">
    <f:validateRegex for="idNum" pattern="(?i-s)(?:[0-9]+){10,16}" />
    <f:ajax immediate="false" event="change" render="idNum-errMsg" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message id="idNum-errMsg" for="idNum" disabled="#{idNum.valid}"  />
```